# android design library toolbar shadow

Tags: android, toolbar, shadow

Trying new android design library I found a bug with toolbar shadow. When using CollapsingToolbarLayout the shadow below toolbar appears only when toolbar collapsed. When we expand it the shadow disappear. My layout looks like

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/user_avatar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

And results 
[image]
There is a shadow when toolbar collapsed.

[image]

But when expand it shadow disappear.

Is there any solutions to solve this problem?
May be there is a way to handle shadow appearance/disappearance?
Thanks.

Comment: It might not be a bug -- it's possible it's meant to be doing the behaviour decribed under "Flexible space with overlapping content" at the bottom of this page: https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling

Comment: Did you find any solution? I think the behaviour is intended, but it's seems like a big hassle if you want the shadow even when expanded. I've tried listening to AppBarLayout offset changes and setting the shadow manually, and also wrapping the AppBarLayout in a RelativeLayout and manually put a shadow below, but nothing works as I want...

Comment: @Thoast83 Post an answer below.

Comment: @RamanBranavitski I don't understand, why post an answer when I'm asking you if you found out a way..? But I actually found a way today, maybe there's a better way, but it works. Do you want me to post that as a solution?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

It seems that the support library team from Google introduced the behavior as part of 24.0.0 but it was kind of buggy so now there is a new workaround you need to do.

1 - Create appbar_always_elevated.xml in animator-v21 folder under res directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:valueTo="8dp"
                        android:valueType="floatType"
                        android:duration="1"/>
    </item>

</selector>
```

2 - In AppBarLayout use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

---

**Old answer**

They fixed this as part of the new support library version (24) so you just need to upgrade and use the correct property.

watch https://youtu.be/w45y_w4skKs?t=31m52s

[image]

---

**Old answer**

I solved this issue by having a `FrameLayout` around the `ViewPager` and setting `android:foreground`.

Attached is the drawable that I am using, and here is the link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/amilcar-andrade/4bfcc68610c5f965d9f666438c508381)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The response of @amilcar-andrade helped me to find the right solution since his link is not correct.

You have to apply the `stateListAnimator` to your AppBarLayout:

example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

and use this xml as animator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="8dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:duration="1"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this code worked for me!

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:elevation="4dp">
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you, but requires min api level 21

Answer (score 0):

I just override `CollapsingToolbarLayout` code like this

```
public class ShadowCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {

private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener mOnOffsetChangedListener;

//constructors

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    ViewParent parent = this.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
        if (mOnOffsetChangedListener != null)
            ((AppBarLayout) parent).addOnOffsetChangedListener(mOnOffsetChangedListener);
    }
}

public void setOnOffsetChangeListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener listener) {
    mOnOffsetChangedListener = listener;
}
}
```

use it in xml instead of native CollapsingToolbarLayout and set listener like this

```
mCollapsingLayout.setOnOffsetChangeListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
                ViewCompat.setElevation(appBarLayout, appBarLayout.getTargetElevation());
            }
        });
```